# Having problems with filter

Tags: php, laravel

I have course search everything works except, when `$r->price` it's returns all courses not last searched ones. I need to catch last "when" and then filter price by it.
How can i do that?

```
 $courses = Course::when($r->mainCat, function ($query) use ($mainCat) {
            $courseIdsArray = Direction::whereIn('course_category_id', $mainCat)->pluck('course_id')->toArray();
            return $query->whereIn('id', $courseIdsArray);
        })->when($r->level, function ($query, $level) {
            return $query->where('level', 'like', "%{$level}%");
        })->when($categories && count($categories) > 0, function ($query) use ($categories) {
            return $query->whereIn('course_category_id', $categories);
        })->when($r->price && in_array($r->price, ['more-expensive', 'less-expensive']), function ($query) use ($r) {
            return $query->orderBy('price', $r->price == 'less-expensive' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        }, function ($query) {
            return $query->statusOn()->order();
        })->paginate(18)->appends($r->query());
```

Comment: instead of `appends()` you can use `withQueryString()`

Comment: how to use it? ->withQueryString($r->query()) getting all courses when filter by price

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't filter by price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391980/cant-filter-by-price)