# Can't filter by price

Tags: php, laravel

I have course search everything works. But i don't know how to make filter by price?
When i filter by price, it's filter but it's filters all courses. But it must filter last filtered courses not all courses. and i don't know how to do it can anyone please help me with this? : )

```
 $courses = Course::when($r->mainCat, function ($query) use ($mainCat) {
            $courseIdsArray = Direction::whereIn('course_category_id', $mainCat)->pluck('course_id')->toArray();
            return $query->whereIn('id', $courseIdsArray);
        })->when($r->level, function ($query, $level) {
            return $query->where('level', 'like', "%{$level}%");
        })->when($categories && count($categories) > 0, function ($query) use ($categories) {
            return $query->whereIn('course_category_id', $categories);
        })


->when($r->price && in_array($r->price, ['more-expensive', 'less-expensive']), function ($query) use ($r) {
            return $query->orderBy('price', $r->price == 'less-expensive' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        })


->paginate(18)->appends($r->query());
```

Comment: and what do you mean by last filtered courses?

Comment: Sorry I mean cloud you dd() your request add it to question

Comment: if someone will filter categories and after that he will filter price it must filter categories by price and now it's filtering all courses by price

Comment: Duplicate of [Having problems with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383384/having-problems-with-filter)